# From Authentication ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication

I have a table which stores user details including username, password and their roles.

I need help on how to login the user using the credential against that in the database. and give access according to the roles

I am stack here.

Please help me ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core utilizes Identity for authentication. Forms auth is incompatible. You'll need to migrate whatever you have now to Identity.

Comment: So ASP.NET Core is not suitable to Web Applications That uses database credentials for logins ? @ChrisPratt

Comment: Of course it is, just not via Forms Auth. Forms auth is part of ASP.NET Membership. ASP.NET Core uses Identity. It's a totally different authentication and authorization infrastructure. See http://asp.net/identity

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.